# Addressing background color of divs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to target multiple `div`s and randomly change the background color, (or other attributes), all at once. I've been able to target the body background with `document.body.style.background` but I'm not sure this would work with multiple elements. Any insight would be nice.

Here is a bit of code that I'm trying to accomplish that with:

```
 function randBGcolor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
        for (var i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
            color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
        }
   document.body.style.background = color;
}
```

I would like to still use the random color function, but have it apply it to many elements on one click.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery and your function:

```
function randBGcolor() {
   var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
   var color = '#';
      for (var i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
         color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
      }
   return color;
}

$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('div.classname').css('background-color', randBGcolor());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this with JQuery, you may be able to find someone who knows how in pure JS.

You can loop through multiple elements, say `div` tags by using `each()`

**http://jsfiddle.net/Kwb49/** - this example changes all `divs` when clicking the body

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').click(function() {
       $('div').each(function() {
            var bgcolor = randBGcolor();
            $(this).css({ "background" : bgcolor });
        }); 
    });

});

function randBGcolor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kwb49/3/ (updated fiddle, works on click, added one test button)

```
function randBGcolor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
        for (var i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
            color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
        }

    return color;

}



 divs=document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
    divs[i].style.backgroundColor=randBGcolor();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `css` method can be used with a callback function, so that you can select all the elements that you want to change, and get a separate background color for each one with a single call:

```
function randBGcolor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
  }
  return color;
}

$('.someelements').css('background-color', randBGcolor);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Tp856/

To use it in a click event, you just use the `click` method inside the `ready` event. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.someelement').click(function(){
    $('.someelements').css('background-color', randBGcolor);
  });
});
```

Note: You should *not* use `Math.random` when you are calculating the random number. That will make the lowest and highest values be selected half as often as the others. Use `Math.floor` and mulitply with a number that is one higher.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I'd suggest, in compliant browsers, using plain JavaScript is:

```
function randColor(n) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));
    }
    return result.join(',');
}

function randBGColor () {
    return 'rgb(' + randColor(3) + ')';
}

var els = document.querySelectorAll('div');

[].forEach.call(els, function(a) {
    a.style.backgroundColor = randBGColor();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Kwb49/2/).